# Error code LNK1561 stopping my code from running

Tags: c++

very new to coding and having trouble with an assignment in c++. I keep getting an error code lnk1561 which google tells me is do with the int main() bit, but no matter what i do i cant figure it out. any help would be appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main();

double pi(int n) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    int sign = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    sum += sign / (2.0*i + 1.0);
    sign *= -1;
    }
    return 4.0*sum;
}
```

Comment: You need to define the main function.  What you have done is provide a declaration of a main function.

Comment: so how do i do that? sorry im really new to this, google told me that when i searched the error but i dont understand it

Comment: every program has an entry point (main) so in your code there's only the prototype thus add definition. another why you prototype main as long as you don't want to call it?

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++? This should be demonstrated therein within the first few pages.

Answer (score 2):

Every program has an entry point (main, WinMain, wmain...) so in your code there's only the prototype thus add definition. Another thing why you prototype main as long as you don't want to call it?

```
int main(); // I think you don't need it here
double pi(int n);

int main()
{
    cout << pi(7.2) << endl; // here you called `pi()`

    return 0;
}

double pi(int n)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    int sign = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
     {
        sum += sign / (2.0*i + 1.0);
        sign *= -1;
    }
    return 4.0*sum;
}
```